# Как правильно передать данные из одного фрагмента в другой, используя CursorLoader? Как правильно использовать Bundle set/getArguments?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment, cursoradaper

Имею активность, из которой через `DrawerLayout` перехожу во фрагменты (их 4)
Не понимаю, как мне передать данные из одного фрагмента в другой.

В первом фрагменте есть listView, в котором выводятся названия блюд, при нажатии по итему (например Pizza) нужно перейти во второй фрагмент, в котором выводятся  связанные с Pizza ингредиенты.

Если нажата Pizza, то выводятся ингредиенты, связанные с Pizza
Если нажат, напрмер Borsh, выводятся ингредиенты, связанные с Borsh

Получаю данные из Бд через `cursorLoader`, пробовал передать данные через `Bundle` (set/getArguments), но я не понимаю, в какие методы надо вписать `set/getArguments`, чтобы вытащить данные из моей базы данных?

Как правильно вытащить данные из БД для `cursorloader`, чтобы спокойно отсортировать ингредиенты по названию блюд?

Первый фрагмент `DishFragment`

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class DishFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1;
    ListView lvData;
    DB db;
    SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;
    public static final String EXTRA_NAME = "extraName";
    Cursor cursor;


    public static final int DISH_LOADER = 0; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    public DishFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dish, container, false);


        // формируем столбцы сопоставления
        String[] from = new String[] {DB.COLUMN_IMGV3, DB.COLUMN_MEAL}; 
        final int[] to = new int[] {R.id.mealIvImg, R.id.mealTvMeal}; 


        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.item_meal,
                null,
                from,
                to,
                0);

        lvData = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.lvDataDish);

        lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(lvData);


        //СЛУШАТЕЛЬ ДЛЯ ЛИСТВЬЮ ПИШЕТСЯ ПОСЛЕ АДАПТЕРА!

        lvData.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_MEAL));
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                CountingFragment countingFragment = new CountingFragment();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString(EXTRA_NAME, name);
                countingFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId(), countingFragment, "visible_frag");
                //ЕСЛИ СДЕЛАТЬ КАК ПЕРВЫМ ПАРАМЕТРОМ ((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId()
                //ТО ПЕРЕКРЫТИЯ ФРАГМЕНТОВ НЕ БУДЕТ!!!!!

                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });

        db = new DB(getActivity());
        db.open();
        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(DISH_LOADER, null, this);


        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        Log.d("tag", "сработал onStop");
       // cursor.close(); при нажатии назад разрушится активность, т.к. backStackToNull работает в onPause
        //db.close(); //при нажатии назад разрушится активность, т.к. backStackToNull работает в onPause
        //getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        db.close();
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        if (id == DISH_LOADER){}
        return new MyCursorLoader(getActivity(), db, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        scAdapter.swapCursor(data);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        scAdapter.swapCursor(null);

    }



    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader{

        Cursor cursor;
        final int LoaderID;
        DB db;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DB db, int id) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
            LoaderID = id;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {

            switch (LoaderID) {
                case DISH_LOADER:
                    cursor = db.getMeal();
                    break;
            }

            //Cursor cursor = db.getMeal();
            return cursor;
        }
    }
}
```

Второй фрагмент `CountingFragment` (в который я перехожу из `lvData.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()`)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

import android.widget.ListView;



/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class CountingFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> { 

    private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1;
    ListView lvData;
    DB db;
    SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;
    public static final int COUNT_LOADER = 1; 

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_counting, container, false);

        // формируем столбцы сопоставления
        String[] from = new String[] {DB.COLUMN_MEAL, DB.COLUMN_INGR, DB.COLUMN_VAL, DB.COLUMN_UNI}; //ССЫЛАЕМСЯ НА СООТВ-ЩИЕ СТОЛБЦЫ БД, ЕСЛИ ИХ НЕТ, ТО СОЗДАЕМ В onUpgrade!!
        final int[] to = new int[] {R.id.countTvMeal, R.id.countTvIngr, R.id.countTvVal, R.id.countTvUni}; //Т.К. НОВЫЙ ФРАГМЕНТ, ТО ПУНКТЫ СОЗДАЮТСЯ В НОВОМ МАКЕТЕ ITEM_MEAL (НЕ ITEM, Т.К. ОН ЕСТЬ)!!


        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.item_counting,
                null,
                from,
                to,
                0);

        lvData = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.lvDataCount);

        lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(lvData);

        db = new DB(getActivity());
        db.open();
        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(COUNT_LOADER, null, this);


        return v;


    }

    public static CountingFragment newInstance(String name) {
        CountingFragment countingFragment = new CountingFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(DishFragment.EXTRA_NAME, name);
        countingFragment.setArguments(arguments);

        return countingFragment;
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, CM_DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.delete_record);
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {
            // получаем из пункта контекстного меню данные по пункту списка
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                    .getMenuInfo();
            // извлекаем id записи и удаляем соответствующую запись в БД
            db.delRec(acmi.id);
            // получаем новый курсор с данными
            getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        db.close();
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new MyCursorLoader(getActivity(), db, id);
    }



    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        scAdapter.swapCursor(data);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
        scAdapter.swapCursor(null);

    }


    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
        Cursor cursor;
        final int LoaderId;
        DB db;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DB db, int id) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
            LoaderId = id;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {


            switch (LoaderId){
                case COUNT_LOADER: cursor = db.getIngr();
                    break;
            }

            return cursor;
        }
    }


}
```

База данных `DB`

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by User on 21.03.2017.
 */

public class DB {

        private static final String DB_NAME = "dbnew"; //ЕСЛИ ТУПИТ МЕНЯЙ ИМЯ БАЗЫ ДАННЫХ!!!!!!!!!
        private static final int DB_VERSION = 3; //МЕНЯЙ ВЕРСИЮ БД ЕСЛИ ДОБАВИЛ СТОЛЬЕЦ!!!
        private static final String DB_TABLE = "mealseat";

        public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_MEAL = "mealing";
        public static final String COLUMN_IMG = "img";
        public static final String COLUMN_INGR = "ingr";
        public static final String COLUMN_VAL = "val";
        public static final String COLUMN_UNI = "uni";
        public static final String COLUMN_IMGV3 = "img3";

        //private static String DB_DELETE = "drop table " + DB_TABLE + ");";


        private static final String DB_CREATE =
                "create table " + DB_TABLE + "(" +
                        COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                        COLUMN_IMG + " integer, " +
                        //COLUMN_MEAL + " text, " +
                        COLUMN_INGR + " text, " +
                        COLUMN_VAL + " text, " +
                        COLUMN_UNI + " text" + ");";

        private final Context mCtx;


        private DBHelper mDBHelper;
        private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

        public DB(Context ctx) {
            mCtx = ctx;
        }

        // открыть подключение
        public void open() {
            mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
            mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }

        // закрыть подключение
        public void close() {
            if (mDBHelper != null) mDBHelper.close();
        }

        // получить все данные из таблицы DB_TABLE
        public Cursor getAllData() {
            return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, DB.COLUMN_MEAL, DB.COLUMN_IMG, DB.COLUMN_INGR, DB.COLUMN_VAL, DB.COLUMN_UNI}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        }


        public Cursor getMeal () {
            //return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_MEAL}, null, null, null, null, null);

            return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_MEAL, COLUMN_IMGV3}, null, null, COLUMN_MEAL, null, null);
        }

        public Cursor getIngr () {
            return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, DB.COLUMN_MEAL, DB.COLUMN_INGR, DB.COLUMN_VAL, DB.COLUMN_UNI}, null, null, /*COLUMN_MEAL + " LIKE ?", Arrays.toString(new String[]{name}),*/ null, null, null);
        }






    /*public String dbDelete() {
        return DB_DELETE;
    }*/

    // добавить запись в DB_TABLE
        public void addRec(int img, int img3, String mealing, String ingr, String val, String uni) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(COLUMN_UNI, uni);
            cv.put(COLUMN_VAL, val);
            cv.put(COLUMN_INGR, ingr);
            cv.put(COLUMN_MEAL, mealing);
            cv.put(COLUMN_IMG, img);
            cv.put(COLUMN_IMGV3, img3);

            mDB.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
        }

        // удалить запись из DB_TABLE
        public void delRec(long id) {
            mDB.delete(DB_TABLE, COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
        }

    /*public void delRecMeal() {
        mDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + DB_TABLE + " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_MEAL);
    }*/


        /*public void delAll (String DB_DELETE) {
            mDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + DB_TABLE);
        }*/

        // класс по созданию и управлению БД
        public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                            int version) {
                super(context, name, factory, version);
            }

            // создаем и заполняем БД
            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);

                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                    cv.put(COLUMN_UNI, + i);
                    cv.put(COLUMN_VAL, + i);
                    cv.put(COLUMN_INGR, + i);
                    cv.put(COLUMN_MEAL, + i);
                    cv.put(COLUMN_IMG, R.drawable.ic_create_black);
                    cv.put(COLUMN_IMGV3, R.drawable.draw_name_eat);

                    db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

                //ЕСЛИ ДОБАВЛЯЕШЬ ХОТЬ ОДИН НОВЫЙ СТОЛБЕЦ - ПИШИ В onUpgrade!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                //ПРИ ЗАПУСКЕ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ ЗАПОМИНАЕТСЯ ЗАДАННОЕ В onCreate КОЛИЧЕСТВО СТОЛБЦОВ!!!!!!
                //ИЛИ ДОБАВЛЯЙ В onUpgrade, ИЛИ СОЗДАВАЙ НОВУЮ БД И ИМЯ ТАБЛЫ!!!!!!!

                String upgradeQuery = "ALTER TABLE " + DB_TABLE + " ADD COLUMN " + COLUMN_MEAL + " TEXT;";
                if (oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2)
                    db.execSQL(upgradeQuery);

                String upgradeQueryV3 = "ALTER TABLE " + DB_TABLE + " ADD COLUMN " + COLUMN_IMGV3 + " INTEGER;";
                if (oldVersion == 2 && newVersion == 3)
                    db.execSQL(upgradeQueryV3);
            }
        }

    }
```

Уже месяц топчусь, переход из одного фрагмента во второй получается, но как то не понятен мне loaderCursor, я не знаю куда впихнуть этот Bundle так, чтобы вытащить его во втором фрагменте, показывая в listView второго фрагмента именно ингредиенты выбранного блюда...

Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прописываем во фрагменте #1 переход во фрагмент #2 (точнее замену фрагмента #1 фрагментом #2 через replace, т.к. интенты для фрагментов не работают).

В моем случае переход осуществлялся через OnItemClickListener листвью.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DB.COLUMN_MEAL));

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    CountingFragment countingFragment = new CountingFragment();

    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();

    arguments.putString("name", name);

    countingFragment.setArguments(arguments);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId(), countingFragment).((ViewGroup)getView().getParent()).getId()addToBackStack(null).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit();

}
```

Следующим шагом во фрагменте #2 я достаю сохраненную строку через getArguments(), но т.к. имею дело с загрузчиками, инициирую сроку в onCreateLoader и классе CursorLoaderCount, и в loadInBackground использую готовую команду sql (подготовленную в классе для работы с БД), которой на вход требуется эта строка.

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String name = getArguments().getString("name"); //строка для получения аргументов создается в onCreateLoader
    return new CursorLoaderCount(getActivity(), db, id, name);
}



@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    scAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
    scAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}


static class CursorLoaderCount extends CursorLoader {
    Cursor cursor;
    final int LoaderId;
    DB db;
    String name;

    public CursorLoaderCount(Context context, DB db, int id, String name) {
        super(context);
        this.db = db;
        LoaderId = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {

        switch (LoaderId){

            case COUNT_LOADER:
                cursor = db.getIngrNew(name);
                break;
        }

        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Метод, возвращающий из класса для работы с БД sql запрос на получение нужных данных с учетом сохраненной строки

```
public Cursor getIngrNew (String name) {
        return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{String.valueOf(COLUMN_CHEKBOX), COLUMN_ID, DB.COLUMN_INGR, DB.COLUMN_VAL, DB.COLUMN_UNI}, DB.COLUMN_MEAL + " = ?", new String[]{name}, null, null, null);
    }
```